# Reusable pop up throwing error at onclick event

Tags: javascript, parceljs

First post here, and newer to Javascript.

I have a node.js / express app that I am building and would like to re-use a yes no pop up in my front end by just changing some variables.
The pop up works and displays the messages, but when I click the yes button I get

Uncaught ReferenceError: yesNoResponse is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

I am using parcel to bundle all my front end scripts, and I have tried declaring the function in multiple places including the index.js which is the root for my parcel bundle.

very confused on this one, any help is greatly appreciated.

```
export const showYesNo = (msg, secondaryMsg, onYes) => {

  function yesNoResponse(option) {
    if (option === 'overWrite') {
      console.log(option);
      hidePopUp();
    }
  }

  const markup = `<div id="popup-yesno" class="modal">
                    <div class="popup-container">
                      <div class="popup-inner-border">
                        <div class="popup-text-border">
                          ${msg}
                          <br />
                          ${secondaryMsg}
                        </div>
                        <div class="popup-button-container">
                          <button class="btn-popup-yes" id="popup-yes-button" onclick="yesNoResponse('${onYes}');">
                            Yes
                          </button>
                          <button class="btn-popup-no" id="popup-no-button" onclick="yesNoResponse('no');">
                            No
                          </button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>`;
  document.querySelector('body').insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', markup);
};
```

Comment: yesNoResponse is not global

Comment: Hey epascarello can you explain a bit further? I have tried to place it in my index.js as well as the javascript file it was called from and it still doesn't seem to find it